# Install i386 package on armhf system?

Tags: package-management, 32-bit

Is it possible? And if yes, how to install them properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No that is not possible. The architectures are different, so your CPU can not execute the binary. You can try to cross compile the package or look for a build for your CPU for that package.

Take a look at [here](https://wiki.linaro.org/Platform/DevPlatform/CrossCompile/CrossbuildingQuickStart), that might help you.